# How can I redirect an url on a Wordpress subdomain when htaccess does not work?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, firefox

Everytime I open my website in Firefox an unwanted redirection directs the site from an url without the www-prefix to an url with the www-prefix.  This results in a warning about an unsafe site, but only in Firefox.

The site is actually a Wordpress subdomain, so sub.domain.com redirects to https://www.sub.domain.com (with www-prefix), while I want it to redirect to https://sub.domain.com (without www-prefix).

I tried to get rid of this redirection with WordPress plugins and with differen codes in htaccess, but I don't get it right.

The contents of my htaccess file is:

...

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
    # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www\.domain.com\/ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 /www.sub.domain.com/ 
    http://sub.domain.com/
```

...

Any suggestions where I go wrong?

Best regards,

Ruud

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Wordpress problem, it's a Firefox problem. I had the same problem. The solution is to **turn off domain name completion**:

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter.
2. A warning page may appear: click the *Accept the risk* and continue button to proceed.
3. Type `fixup` in the Search: field located at the top of the `about:config` page.
4. Double-click the `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` preference to change the value to **false**.